# Typescript not nested object type

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, nested

I want to declare generic object type that is **not nested** (value is not object/array, **only primitive**)

For example:

Valid:

```
{
 a:"value",
 b:false,
 c:4
}
```

Invalid:

```
{
a:{b:"c"}
}

{
a:[5]
}
```

Something like this (of course it's invalid declaration):

```
interface NotNestedObject  {
  [x: any]: not Array/Object;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily there aren't many primitive types in typescript, so you can just simply list them all in a union type.

```
interface NotNestedObject  {
    [x: string]: number|boolean|string|null|undefined;
}
```

if you want dates to be included

```
interface NotNestedObject  {
    [x: string]: number|boolean|string|Date|null|undefined;
}
```

if you want functions also to be included

```
interface NotNestedObject  {
    [x: string]: number|boolean|string|Date|Function|null|undefined;
}
```

And of course you can remove null and undefined if you don't want them to be allowed. They are included by default unless you enable strictNullChecks compiler option.